# Unable to build CDT product

Tags: maven, eclipse-cdt

I have an eclipse based product which uses `CDT 8.1`. For some project specific reasons we want to patch the `CDT plugin` and create our own distribution.

I followed the steps from [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development#Building_the_CDT_p2_repository) and cloned the source code from the branch `cdt_8.1`.

Then I tried to build the code as it is but I am stuck at the `mvn package` command. I get the following error (tried with several maven versions `>3.3`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession.getRepositorySession()Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystemSession;
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.utils.PluginRealmHelper.execute(PluginRealmHelper.java:86)
```

Comment: You may have more luck getting an answer on [cdt-dev](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/cdt-dev).

Comment: Found there is an incompatibility between the `tycho-version` specified in the `pom.xml` file and the `maven` version requested. For `maven` version `>3.3.1` you should add in command line `mvn package -Dtycho-version=0.18.1`